# The only code in action is RedirectToAction but still Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have done some searching on the error but the results all have to do with using `try..catch` or `if` statements. In my case I am just adding some info to the DB and then doing a `RedirectToAction` call, I figure since I am not technically calling the `return` keyword this is the root of the problem but what am I supposed to return and where when all I want to do is the redirect?

```
[Route("AddMTNLoctionNote", Name = "Add Location Note")]
public ActionResult AddMTNLocationNote()
{
    using (var db = new JobSightDbContext())
    {
        var newNote = new MTNAlarmLocationNote()
        {
            LocationID = int.Parse(Request["LocationID"]),
            Note = Request["Note"]
        };

        db.MTNAlarmLocationNotes.Add(newNote);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    RedirectToAction("MTNAlarmDetail", int.Parse(Request["LocationID"]));
}
```

Comment: You answer the question in your question, you must return the redirect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to `return` `RedirectToAction()`'s result, not just call the method:

```
return RedirectToAction("MTNAlarmDetail", int.Parse(Request["LocationID"]));
```